# discord.py multiple select menu interactions get mixed up

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been setting up a report interaction for my sim-racing discord community.

This interaction exists of two parts:

The first part is a view with 4 select menus. Every time one of these gets selected, it puts a check value to 1. Once all four of these check values are 1 it advances to a modal where the User is asked to give additional text input. When the User submits the modal all the entered information gets posted as an embed message into a thread in a forum channel.

My problem is that if multiple users fill in the report form at the same time, their inputs get mixed up. Is it possible that this is happening, because I'm storing the user inputs in global variables which get overwritten once another user makes a selection?

How could I avoid this? I don't know what to try... I thought Discord creates an instance for each interaction so that each interaction uses its own variables.. but it does not seem that this is the case here...

*What is the best way to implement multiple select menus in general?* - I don't like my global variable attempt with these "select_check" variables.

*Also: Is there maybe a way to lock the command for User B until User A is compeletely finished with filling the form?* - I could only think of a cooldown, but I wan't to avoid this.

**EDIT:** I tried to simplify the code and broke it down to two select menus so it might be easier to understand, but since I wanted to keep some essentials, it is still pretty long, sorry about that.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import View
from discord import app_commands
import json


with open('krfconfig.json') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

class SurveyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title='Report'):

    wann = discord.ui.TextInput(label='When did it happen?', placeholder="z.B. Rennen Runde 15", max_length=40)
    was = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Give us a short description', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=1000)
    media = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Media', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=500, placeholder="Videos/Screenshots vorher hochladen und hier als Link posten, z.B Youtube, Streamable etc..")

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        global reported_user
        global selected_track
        global channel

        author = interaction.user.name
        auticon = interaction.user.display_avatar
        repuser_string = ''
        for elem in reported_user:
            repuser_string = repuser_string + ', ' + elem.name

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Report-Ticket', color=discord.Color.magenta())
        embed.set_author(name=author, icon_url=auticon)
        embed.add_field(name='Report against:', value=f'{repuser_string} \n\u200b', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='When it happened:', value=f'{str(self.wann)} \n\u200b', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Short description:', value=f'{str(self.was)} \n\u200b', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Media:', value=str(self.media), inline=False)

        thr_name = f"{str(selected_track)}-Report: {author} vs. {repuser_string}"
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Report gesendet!', ephemeral=True)
        await channel.create_thread(name=thr_name, content=f'Reportverfahren: {interaction.user.mention} vs. {repuser_string}', embed=embed)


class Select1(discord.ui.UserSelect):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(placeholder="Who do you want to Report?", max_values=19, min_values=1)
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        global select1_check
        global select2_check
        global reported_user

        reported_user = self.values
        select1_check = 1
        print(reported_user)

        if select1_check and select2_check == 1:
            await interaction.response.send_modal(SurveyModal())
            await interaction.delete_original_response()
        else:
            await interaction.response.defer()


class Select2(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Australia"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Bahrain"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Belgiium")]
        super().__init__(placeholder="Which Track?", max_values=1, min_values=1, options=options)
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        global select1_check
        global select2_check
        global selected_track

        selected_track = self.values[0]
        select2_check = 1

        if select1_check and select2_check == 1:
            await interaction.response.send_modal(SurveyModal())
            await interaction.delete_original_response()
        else:
            await interaction.response.defer()


class Report(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Report cog loaded.')


    @app_commands.command(name="report", description='Use this to Report others!')
    @app_commands.checks.has_any_role('Liga A', 'Liga B', 'Liga C', 'Liga A Reserve', 'Liga B Reserve', 'Liga C Reserve')
    async def fillsurvey(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        global select1_check
        global select2_check
        global channel

        channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(config["REPORT_CHANNEL"])

        myView = View(timeout=300)
        myView.add_item(Select1())
        myView.add_item(Select2())

        select1_check = 0
        select2_check = 0

        await interaction.response.send_message(view=myView, ephemeral=True)


async def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Report(bot))
```

Comment: An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is expected (there are nearly 200 lines of code). For example, applying the [zero one infinity rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule), five of things could probably be reduced down to two.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I edited the post and tried to shorten the code to its essentials!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think the problem were the global variables.. I took a different approach by using nested dicts and this seems to work just fine..

an example:

```
class Select2(discord.ui.Select):
def __init__(self):
    options=[
        discord.SelectOption(label="Australia"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Bahrain"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Belgiium")]
    super().__init__(placeholder="Which Track?", max_values=1, min_values=1, options=options)
async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    global repinfos
    
    clname = f'{interaction.user.name}#{interaction.user.discriminator}'
    repinfos[clname]['track'] = self.values[0]
    repinfos[clname]['s1check'] = 1
    await checkforpart2(interaction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass `View` and add in class attributes there. You can then use `self.view` in Selects to access the view and it's attributes. You can also pass these values to the Modal rather than relying on global vars as well.

```py
class SurveyModal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self, reported_user, track, channel):
        super().__init__(title="Report")
        self.reported_user = reported_user
        self.track = track
        self.channel = channel

        wann = discord.ui.TextInput(label='When did it happen?', placeholder="z.B. Rennen Runde 15", max_length=40)
        was = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Give us a short description', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=1000)
        media = discord.ui.TextInput(label='Media', style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph, max_length=500, placeholder="Videos/Screenshots vorher hochladen und hier als Link posten, z.B Youtube, Streamable etc..")

        self.add_item(wann)
        self.add_item(was)
        self.add_item(media)

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        # access the values you need using `self.`
        print(self.reported_user)
        print(self.track) 
        print(self.channel)


class Select1(discord.ui.UserSelect):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(placeholder="Who do you want to Report?", max_values=19, min_values=1)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        reported_user = self.values
        self.view.reported_user = reported_user
        self.view.s1_check = True
        print(reported_user)

        if self.view.s1_check and self.view.s2_check:
            channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(config["REPORT_CHANNEL"])
            modal = SurveyModal(self.view.reported_user, self.view.track, channel)
            await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
            await interaction.delete_original_response()
        else:
            await interaction.response.defer()


class Select2(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Australia"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Bahrain"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Belgiium")]
        super().__init__(placeholder="Which Track?", max_values=1, min_values=1, options=options)

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):

        selected_track = self.values[0]
        self.view.track = selected_track
        self.view.s2_check = True

        if self.view.s1_check self.view.s2_check:
            channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(config["REPORT_CHANNEL"])
            modal = SurveyModal(self.view.reported_user, self.view.track, channel)
            await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)
            await interaction.delete_original_response()
        else:
            await interaction.response.defer()


class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__(timeout=300)
        self.track = None
        self.reported_user = None
        self.s1_check = False
        self.s2_check = False
        
        self.add_item(Select1())
        self._add_item(Select2())
```

Then, you just need to do `view = MyView()` to create an instance of it and send that. There's no need for global variables.

I also changed the `s1_check/s2_check` to be bools. Just makes it clearer that that's what you want them to be and act like.